# Compare dropdown with value not key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am fetching user data in the model and using SelectList, fetching the country detail with name and ID.

```
ID             Name
1              USA
2              UK
3              CANADA
```

On my page, I have TEXTBOX, in which I am displaying the country NAME USA which is fetched from the model. Now SAME COUNTRY NAME I WANT TO KEEP SELECTED in my dropdown also.

```
var GetNewCountry = new SelectList(_manualGridService.GetCountry().OrderBy(l => l.Name)
.ToDictionary(us => us.ID, us => us.Name), "Key", "Value");

ViewBag.GetNewCountry = GetNewCountry ;
```

here is my view dropdown code

```
<div class="form-group">
<select asp-for="ConId" asp-items="@ViewBag.GetNewCountry" class="form-control">
   <option value=""> Select </option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="ConId" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

Parameter details

```
 public int ConId { get; set; }
```

Here is my textbox code with parameter

```
public string UserConName{ get; set; }
```

```
<div class="form-group">
<input asp-for="UserConName" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Country Name" style="width:107%" />
</div>
```

The **UserConName**, textbox contains value **USA**, I want to keep seleted **USA** in my DROPDOWN LIST also.

**MY SOLUTION**

```
string strId = "";
                foreach (var item in GetNewCountry )
                {
                    if (item.Text == res.ConName)
                    {
                        strId = item.Value;
                    }
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strId))
                {
                    res.ConId= int.Parse(strId);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Shorten Answer

```
var GetNewCountry = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var item in _manualGridService.GetCountry().OrderBy(l => l.Name).ToDictionary(us => us.ID, us => us.Name))
{
    GetNewCountry.Add(new SelectListItem() { 
                                              Value = item.Key.ToString(), 
                                              Text = item.Value, 
                                              Selected = item.Value == "USA" ? true : false 
    });
}
ViewBag.GetNewCountry = GetNewCountry ;
```

---

### Detailed explanation

Firstly you need know, by using `new  SelectList(_manualGridService.GetCountry().OrderBy(l => l.Name) .ToDictionary(us => us.ID, us => us.Name), "Key", "Value")`, the `Key` equals to `Id`'s value, the `Value` equals to `Name`'s value.

Then compare with this constructor definition: `public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField)`, we can know that `ID` represents the `<option>`'s **value**, 'Name' represents the `<option>`'s **text**.

```
<option value="IDValue">NameValue</option>
```

Finally the `SelectList` contains another constructor which can set the dropdownlist selected value:

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue)
```

Above all, in your scenario the selected value does not match the `ID`, it matched `Name` value, so you need change the `SelectList` like below：

```
var GetNewCountry = new SelectList(_manualGridService.GetCountry().OrderBy(l => l.Name)
                          .ToDictionary(us => us.ID, us => us.Name), "Value", "Value","USA");
```

Generated html:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The ConId field is required." id="ConId" name="ConId">
    <option value=""> Select </option>
    <option selected="selected" value="NameValue1">NameValue1</option>
    <option value="NameValue2">NameValue2</option>
    //...
</select>
```

### Note:

In this way you can get the `value="USA"` option selected, **but another question**, your select `<select asp-for="ConId">` here binds value to `ConId`, but the option value now represents `Name`, so it cannot bind successfully if you do form submit.

So **if you do not want to change** the `<select asp-for="ConId">` to `<select asp-for="UserConName">`, you need modify your backend code like below:

```
var GetNewCountry = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var item in _manualGridService.GetCountry().OrderBy(l => l.Name).ToDictionary(us => us.ID, us => us.Name))
{
    GetNewCountry.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = item.Key.ToString(), Text = item.Value, Selected = item.Value == "USA" ? true : false });
}
ViewBag.GetNewCountry = GetNewCountry ;
```